# Filtering data based on category in React functional component

Tags: reactjs, json, sorting, react-hooks, filtering

This is my first ecommerce project in React.js.
I am showing product listing where i am showing the categories also on the left side, as in the below screenshot you can see.

I am trying to filter the product listing based on category. Hence i am very close to achieve it but i am facing an error (memory leak issue).

**Error:**
Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

where am i making mistake?
**here is the screenshot:**

[image]

**here is the code:**

```
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCategories, setSelectedCategories] = useState([]);


//handling paging
const handlePageChange = (pageNumber) => {
  if (
    pageNumber > 0 &&
    pageNumber <= products.length / 15 &&
    pageNumber !== page
  )
    setPage(pageNumber); 
    
}


const addCategory = (category) => {
  if(!selectedCategories.includes(category)){
      setSelectedCategories(prev => ([...prev, category]))
  }     
}



const removeCategory = (category) => {
  if(selectedCategories.includes(category)){
      const removedList = selectedCategories.filter((item) => (item !== category));
      setSelectedCategories(removedList);
  }
}

const getCategories = () => { 
  fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products/categories')
  .then(res => res.json())  
  .then((data) => {
    setCategories(data);
  })  
  
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

useEffect(() => {
  getCategories() 
  }, [])



const getProducts = () => {
  fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products?limit=90') 
  .then(res => res.json()) 
  .then((data) => {
    if (data.products && data.products.length) setProducts(data.products);
  })  

  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}



useEffect(() => {
getProducts()
}, [])



useEffect(() => {
  if(selectedCategories.length === 0){
      setProducts(products);

  } else{
    setProducts(products.filter((item)=>(selectedCategories.includes(item.category))));
  }
}, [selectedCategories, products])
```

here is JSX code:
showing category.

```
{categories.map((category) => (
  <div onClick={() => {
    if(selectedCategories.includes(category)){
        removeCategory(category);
    } else{
        addCategory(category);
    }
}}  key={category}> 

      <div className="form-check">
        <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value={category} id={category} />
        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor={category}>
        {category}     
        </label>
      </div> 
  </div>

))}
```

showing product listing.

```
  {products.length && (
    <div className='row'>
      {products.slice(page * 15- 15, page * 15).map((item)  => (

        <div className='col-lg-4 mb-4 text-center' key={item.id}>
        <div className='product' key={item.id}> 
        <Link to={`/shop/${item.id}/${item.title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()}`}>
        <div className='list'>
            <div className='p_photo'>
                <img className='img-fluid' src={item.thumbnail} alt={item.title} /> 
            </div>
            
        </div>
        </Link>

        <div className="Stars" style={{"--rating": [item.rating]}} />

        <div className='title mt-2'> <Link to={`/shop/${item.id}/${item.title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()}`}>{item.title}</Link> </div>
              
        <div className='price mt-2'>    
        <span className='sale'>${item.price}</span> 
        <span className='discount'>({item.discountPercentage}% OFF)</span> 
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      
      ))}

    </div>
  )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue arises when the component mounts, invoking `getProducts()` within the first useEffect. Upon fetching the data, it updates the `products` state, triggering the second useEffect with `[selectedCategories, products]` as the dependency array.

If `selectedCategories` is an empty array, the second useEffect enters the if statement, calling `setProducts(products)`, and triggers the useEffect once again, leading to recursion.

```
const getProducts = () => {
  fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products?limit=90') 
  .then(res => res.json()) 
  .then((data) => {
    if (data.products && data.products.length) setProducts(data.products);
  })  
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

useEffect(() => {
  getProducts()
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  if(selectedCategories.length === 0){
    setProducts(products);
  } else{
    setProducts(
      products.filter(
       (item) => selectedCategories.includes(item.category)
      )
    );
  }
}, [selectedCategories, products])
```

To address this issue, you can either filter the values in the rendering part without changing the `products` state or introduce another state `filteredProducts`.

1. Filtering in the rendering part:

```
{products.length && (
    <div className='row'>
      {products
        .filter((item) => selectedCategories.includes(item.category))
        .slice(page * 15 - 15, page * 15)
        .map((item) => <.. rendering are the same.. >)
      }
    </div>
)}
```

2. Creating another state to manage filters:

```
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);
```

Modify your useEffect to update the filtered state:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(selectedCategories.length === 0){
    setFilteredProducts(products);
  } else {
    setFilteredProducts(
     products.filter(
      (item) => selectedCategories.includes(item.category)
     )
    );
  }
}, [selectedCategories, products])
```

Then, in the rendering part, use `filteredProducts` instead of products:

```
{filteredProducts.length && (
    <div className='row'>
      {filteredProducts
        .filter((item) => selectedCategories.includes(item.category))
        .slice(page * 15 - 15, page * 15)
        .map((item) => <.. rendering are the same.. >)
      }
    </div>
)}
```

*Note*: In case you want to reset the products state with each filter update, going back to the initial state requires another server request to retrieve products. Using a second state allows you to easily implement reset logic, such as using `setFilteredProducts(products)` or a similar approach.